# Model Structure & has_many Association Migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set up models in such a way that Users can create Lessons and then other users can sign up for them.

Right now my models are set up like this:

```
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :teacher, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :students, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lessons
  has_many :students, :through => :lessons
end
```

I want to be able to access the users signed up for a lesson by @lesson.students for example. I'd also like to be able to get all the lessons that a student is participating in (can't really see how I'd do this with my current set up).

Are my model associations right for how I'd like to use them? If so, how can I create the migrations to add the necessary references to my database models?

Comment: What about `@student.lessons.all` to see all the lessons?

Comment: Wouldn't this also show lessons that the user is teaching? @AlexZakruzhetskyi

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ability to create nested resources from it's parents then you have to add:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for
```

to the parent model.

Also, I recommend you to read [how to set up `has_many through` relationships](https://gist.github.com/wrburgess/2187164), you **need** a join model for rails to do its magic and link the 2 models

Once you set everything up, create the join model (with it's respective foreign keys, one for lesson and the other for user) rails will take care of the associations between the models, allowing you to do things like:

```
User.last.lessons #lessons created by the last user
```

and

```
Lesson.first.users #users subscribed to a lesson, in this case the first one
```

Comment: The join model will just keep a reference to every single occurrence of `User` and `Lesson` with entries like: `user_id:1, lesson_id:1, created_at:timestamp, updated_at:timestamp`.

Comment: so when you look up `User.last.lessons` rails will iterate over this join model (call it whatever you want) and retrieve the user instances for you to work with.

Comment: Just to see if I understand correctly: I would create a Student join model that keeps track of a Lesson id and the User id. This means that a Lesson `has_many :students` and `belongs_to :user`, a Student `has_one :user` and `has_one :lesson`, and a User `has_many :lessons`, `has_many :students :through => :lessons` (students taking my lessons), and `has_many :students` (lessons I'm taking). It seems to me like this might be problematic because User.last.students would give both lessons I'm taking and students taking my lessons. @bang-bang

Comment: No. If you want to relate `User` and `Lesson` you'll have to find a relationship in between. Let's say you create a join model called `Lecture` to keep a track on students (users) and their lessons. This way, if you do `User.first.lessons` rails will look up for the lessons using the join model lectures. For this to work, follow the gist, is very straightforward once you understand it logically